# MySQL Storing a Variable

Tags: php, mysql, variables, search, redundancy

I have a query to search for user using a searchString against first name and last name concatenated. Here is my code:

```
  $query = " SELECT user_id, firstname, lastname, picUrl
              FROM user
              WHERE CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) LIKE '%" . $searchString . "%'
              ORDER BY CASE WHEN CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) = '" . $searchString . "' THEN 0
                            WHEN CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) = '" . $searchString . "%' THEN 1
                            WHEN CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) = '%" . $searchString . "%' THEN 2
                            WHEN CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) = '%" . $searchString . "' THEN 3
                            ELSE 4
                        END, CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) ASC";
```

Is there a way to make my code cleaner by storing "CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname)" as a variable called full_name?

Examples,

```
WHERE full_name LIKE ... 

WHEN full_name = ...
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?? could you share sample output for your query ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = " SELECT user_id, firstname, lastname, picUrl, 
                  CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) AS full_name
          FROM user
          WHERE full_name LIKE '%" . $searchString . "%'
          ORDER BY CASE WHEN full_name = '" . $searchString . "' 
                            THEN 0
                        WHEN full_name = '" . $searchString . "%' 
                            THEN 1
                        WHEN full_name = '%" . $searchString . "%' 
                            THEN 2
                        WHEN full_name = '%" . $searchString . "' 
                            THEN 3
                        ELSE 4
                    END, full_name ASC";
```

According to want you want to do, you could ever omit `firstname, lastname,` in the SELECT part.

Answer (score 1):

The above didn't work. I found this to work though:

```
$query = " SELECT user_id, firstname, lastname, picUrl, firstname + ' ' + lastname as fullname  
           FROM user
           WHERE CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) LIKE '%" . $searchString . "%'
           ORDER BY CASE WHEN fullname = '" . $searchString . "' THEN 0 
                         WHEN fullname = '" . $searchString . "%' THEN 1
                         WHEN fullname = '%" . $searchString . "%' THEN 2
                         WHEN fullname = '%" . $searchString . "' THEN 3
                         ELSE 4
                    END, full_name DESC";
```